# What officially published adventures contain yuan-ti?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, yuan-ti

I've been searching for officially published adventures containing yuan-ti, but I've only found *Tomb of Annihilation* and a brief mention in *Hoard of the Dragon Queen*. Are there any other published adventures with yuan-ti in them?

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Ren, take the [tour] when you have a moment. Unfortunately, recommendation questions are generally off topic (see [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5747/62294) for details). You might ask your question at a traditional forum, see [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) for our curated list.

Comment: However, I think your question could be made on topic by focusing on officially published adventures that feature Yuan-Ti. Opening it up to homebrew content makes the net much too broad, but limiting the question to "What officially published adventures feature Yuan-Ti?" should be on topic here, as it is less "recommend an adventure to me" and more about making observations about a well-defined list of adventures.

Comment: Note that a question being closed isn't necessarily permanent. If you choose to [edit] your question (using the Edit button just below the tags at the bottom left of the question) and edit into a state that is on-topic it can be re-opened.

Comment: I've added the [dnd-5e] tag since the modules you mention are 5e modules.

Comment: @Ren Are you interested in officially published adventures from D&D editions outside of the current edition (5e)? Whether 'yes' or 'no', I think that would be worth clarifying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yuan-Ti are featured in some capacity in the following adventures:

- *Tomb of Annihilation*
- *Rise of Tiamat*
- *Candlekeep Mysteries*: "Book of Cylinders"
- *Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage*
- *Storm King's Thunder*
- *Hoard of the Dragon Queen*
- *Storm Lord's Wrath*
- *Tales from the Yawning Portal*

  - "The Hidden Shrine of Tamoachan"
  - "Dead in Thay"

Obviously not every adventure has the same level of interest in Yuan-Ti, *Tomb of Annihilation* seems to have more engagement with Yuan-Ti than any other adventure.

I obtained this list using the DND Beyond phone app. It allows you to search all installed content for any search term and returns a complete list of results. I happen to have every book installed in my phone, so searching "Yuan" yielded every appearance of the word in the D&D 5e corpus. From here, it was a matter of checking results from adventures for relevancy and providing the list.

Comment: It may be worth noting that D&D Beyond also has a website – but the website's search results can't be filtered by book, and [it looks like it only returns up to the first 35 results](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=yuan&f=actions,compendium,conditions,skills,rules,weapon-property&c=compendium) (so it's impossible to tell whether there are additional results beyond that list). I know the app lets you search within an individual book; can you do that if you don't own the book (I'm guessing not)?